# How can i stop this program by giving some input?

Tags: c, scanf, atoi

I was trying to filter out integers from input, without using getchar() function, 
To be exact, i was trying to read coefficients and powers from 1x^2 + 3x^6 + 5x^0, that's when i ended up writing this program, it is not complete program, it was supposed to be a part of program .

```
int main(){
    int a , b, i = 0, n;
    char c[2];
    while(5){
        if(scanf("%1s", c) == 1){
            if( (n = atoi(c)) != 0 || (*c == 48) ){
               printf("%d", n);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so what is correct way of doing it?
what are some modifications?
thanks :)

Comment: What's wrong with `getchar()`? But if you want to read a number, use `%d`.

Comment: what the exact input?

Answer (score 0):

if this `1x^2 + 3x^6 + 5x^0` is your exact input, you can use `scanf` to scan it.

```
    int powers[3];
    int coefficients[3];
    if (scanf("%dx^%d + %dx^%d + %dx^%d", &coefficients[0], &powers[0], &coefficients[1], &powers[1], &coefficients[2], &powers[2]) != 6)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```